# How to parse nested json object as it is using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
   "sets": [
      {...},
      {
         "id": "id",
         "html": "<html></html>",
         "javascript": "{onError: function (event) {}}",
         "css": ".someclass {}",
         "translations": {
            "en": { "LABEL_1": "Some label text", "HEADER_1": "Some header text" },
            "fr": { "LABEL_1": "Some label text", "HEADER_1": "Some header text" }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I have an object that represents this JSON for deserialization purpose

```
@Data //Lombok
@NoArgsConstructor //Lombok
public class Set {
   @JsonProperty("screenSetID")
    private String screenSetID;
    @JsonProperty("html")
    private String html;
    @JsonProperty("css")
    private String css;
    @JsonProperty("javascript")
    private String javascript;
    @JsonProperty("translations")
    private String translations;
}
```

I have the following piece of code to deserialize JSON

```
private List<Set> parseSetsData(String json) {
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   
   try {
     return mapper.readValue(json, TypeReference<List<Set>(){});
   } catch (IOException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}
```

How I can parse **translations** JSON object as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Jason object could be mapped to `Map<String, Object>` and any Json List could be mapped to `List<Object>`. So you could parse your JSON as follows:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModules(new JavaTimeModule());
objectReader = objectMapper.reader();
Map<String, Object> parsedJson = (Map<String, Object>)objectReader.forType(Map.class).readValue(jsonString)
```

Note that your JSON is a JSON object and not JSON list, so this example parses it to Map

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you understand that the that you want is part of on array hats why I had to use a for loop:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode treeNode = mapper.readTree(json);
treeNode=treeNode.findValue("sets");
for (Iterator<JsonNode> it = treeNode.elements(); it.hasNext(); ) {
   JsonNode node = it.next();
   String theValueYouWant=node.findValue("translations").textValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json I found that when you deserialize your item it should look like the following;

```
public class En
{
    @JsonProperty("LABEL_1")
    public String lABEL_1;
    @JsonProperty("HEADER_1")
    public String hEADER_1;
}

public class Fr
{
    @JsonProperty("LABEL_1")
    public String lABEL_1;
    @JsonProperty("HEADER_1")
    public String hEADER_1;
}

public class Translations
{
    public En en;
    public Fr fr;
}

public class Set
{
    public String id;
    public String html;
    public String javascript;
    public String css;
    public Translations translations;
}
```

However, in your class, "translations" is a string, but in a JSON structure, it points to an object.