# How to get nested array values in main class - JSON to POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
   "types":[
      {
         "slot":1,
         "type":{
            "name":"grass",
            "url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
         }
      },
      {
         "slot":2,
         "type":{
            "name":"poison",
            "url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I need only names of types, so I'd like to have something like this:

```
public class MainClass {

    private List<String> types;
}
```

I want to avoid creating of nested classes. How can I get this result?

Comment: Why, _specifically_, do you want to avoid creating more classes?

Comment: "Types" is a field of Pokemon class. I want to easily iterate through types, which particular pokemon has.

Comment: You haven't explained why you are trying to avoid making a `List<Type>`.

Comment: Because then I can use `types.contains(name)`, to check if particular Pokemon has a given type and don't need to iterate over all of types list and check if every Type.name equals given type.

Comment: Perhaps at this point you should just use JsonPath (though I wouldn't think twice about `types.stream().filter(t -> name.equals(t.getName()).findFirst()`, or the much cleaner `types.find { it.name == name }` in Groovy).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to convert your JSON to map and retrieve from there the List and from each element get Map and get the value by key type. Here is the [link to a question on how to parse your JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423583/how-to-parse-nested-json-object-as-it-is-using-jackson/65424016#65424016). The rest should be trivial

Answer (score 0):

Using Jackson, you can do:

```
ArrayNode types = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStr).withArray("types");

List<String> typeNames = IntStream.range(0, types.size())
        .mapToObj(types::get)
        .map(json -> json.get("type")
            .get("name")
            .asText())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or using [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json), you can do:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getJSONArray("types");

List<String> typeNames = IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length())
        .mapToObj(jsonArray::getJSONObject)
        .map(json -> json.getJSONObject("type")
                .getString("name"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Both return the output:

```
[grass, poison]
```